# Equivalence Classes with 1 or 2 elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, equivalence-relations

6. Let ~ be the relation on $\mathbb R$ defined by
   a ~ b if and only if |a| = |b|:

(a) Prove that is an equivalence relation.
(b) Give an example of an equivalence class with two elements.
(c) Give an example of an equivalence class with one element.
(d) Give a complete set of equivalence class representatives.

I can do part (a) of the question by showing the symmetry, reflexivity and transitivity but I'm struggling with the rest of the question. Can anyone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your equivalence class is $\pm a$ for some number $a$.  So give an example where $+a \neq -a$ and give an example where $+a = -a$.

Comment: So for part (b) an equivalence class could be {1,-1} or {2,-2} etc. and part (c) can only be {0}

Comment: Would that make part (c) {0,1,2,3,.......} i.e. all n in Z*

Comment: (b) and (c) are good, but for your representatives why are you choosing only elements from Z?  Isn't your equivalence on R?

Comment: Ah good point, thanks a lot!